# How to use Firebase Crashlytics on Android v14 devices

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

We have about 350+ kiosk devices that runs Android 14 - 16 and as far as we understand these will not be able to use Firebase Crashlytics after November, since min sdk has to be 16. We tried overrideLibrary in Manifest, but that doesn't work.

Anyone else have this problem or maybe a solution to it? We have used crashlytics for many years and are super happy with it, so would be a shame to remove it now. Because the alternative of changing 350+ devices overnight is a Financial nightmare.

EDIT: wrote wrong SDK version, is of course 16.

Comment: Did you start moving to Crashlytics when it was announced [over 2 years ago](https://fabric.io/blog/the-future-of-fabric)? I don't think ~2.5 years qualifies as "overnight", particularly since that deadline was already extended from mid 2019 to November 2020.

Comment: Don't understand your comment? We are already using Firebase, but we have many devices that are below v17, which is the issue. Should we as a company have thrown out working Kiosk because this would happen? 

I'm asking if there is a way to get Crashlytics to run below v17 after november?

Comment: The move to [a minSdkVersion of 16](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/google-play-services-discontinuing.html) was announced in December 2018. What makes you think the minSdkVersion is 17?

Comment: I apologize for writing wrong, of course it is SDK 16. Now is there a solution, or do we need to drop Crashlytics from our app from november?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Firebase Android Release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-05-07), it was on May 7th, 2019 that Firebase updated their `minSdkVersion` to API level 16, over 6 months after [Google Play services updated their `minSdkVersion`](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/google-play-services-discontinuing.html).

As per the [Firebase Crashlytics SDK blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/06/crashlytics-sdk-now-available.html), you must upgrade to Firebase [Crashlytics 17.0.0+](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#crashlytics_v17-0-0) for Android to continue to receive crash reports after November 15, 2020. Crashlytics 17.0.0 was released on April 23, 2020 - after the `minSdkVersion` has been raised to API level 16.

Therefore there is no way to use Firebase Crashlytics on API 14 or 15 devices. You would need to ensure that all of those devices are running API 16 or higher to continue to use Firebase Crashlytics on them.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A real shame, Android Studio did the same in a earlier release, just removed possibility for testing cpu, mem and gpu usage in earlier sdk version. :-(

Comment: I'm in Africa and we have alot of users with devices running below api 16.  looks like we now have to move to a third party crashlytics provider.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum [SDK](https://esper.io/developer) version for Firebase is Jelly Bean (API 16), according to the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). As of 2020, there is no way around this.
In the near future the minimum SDK will be bumped to API 23.

Comment: Sorry the near future to API 23, when is that surpose to happen? Because then we need to drop Firebase totally, since most of our current devices are below API 23.